# Cusorfetch Error - too many in the into list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please could someone help with the below - I did post this last week, I did get the code running but someone had then deleted the code. Could someone help?

The error I am getting is -

Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

```
  -- declare cursor variables
  declare @PKCustomerRecord int, @Agent varchar(100), @CallBackDateTime datetime
  declare @Title varchar(15), @Forename varchar(30), @Surname varchar(30), 
          @Address1 varchar(50), @Address2 varchar(50), @Address3 varchar(50), @Address4 varchar(50), @Address5 varchar(50), 
          @PostCode varchar(10), @ContactNumber varchar(16), @Telephone2 varchar(16), 
          @DOB datetime, @Source varchar(30), @list_id int, @user_group varchar(8), @campaign_id varchar(8), @ViciDialID int, 
          @PKUsers int, @LeadId int, @ViciUser varchar(20), @Comments varchar(max)


  -- declare cursor
 declare csr cursor for 
  select 
        ViciDialID, PKUsers, CallBackDateTime, CallBackDateTime, [user] as Agent,
        ci.PKCustomerRecord, ci.Title, ci.Forename, ci.Surname,
        ci.Address1, ci.Address2, ci.Address3, ci.Address4, ci.Address5, ci.PostCode,
        ci.DOB, case when ci.Source = 'CB' then ci.ContactLoadSource else ci.Source end as Source,
        cb.ContactNumber,
        case when cb.ContactNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT <> ci.Telephone1 then ci.Telephone1 
        when cb.ContactNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT <> Telephone2 then Telephone2 end as Telephone2,
        case 
        when ci.Source = 'SASurvey' then 8890 
        when ci.Source = 'AAR' then 8891
        when ci.Source = 'CB' then 8893
        when ci.Source = 'RTA' then 8894
        when ci.Source = 'Verve Survey' then 8895
        when ci.Source = 'Unregistered' then 8892 end as list_id, user_group, campaign_id,
        cb.Comments
  from CAGSQL.CallCenter.dbo.CallBacks cb with (nolock)
  join #ViciDialData u with (nolock) on cb.UserFK = u.PKUsers
  join CAGSQL.ConsumerCare.dbo.ContactInfo ci with (nolock) on cb.ContactInfoFK = ci.PKCustomerRecord  
  where PoolFK = '173'
  and CallBackDateTime >= getdate()  
  and CallBackDateTime <= convert(varchar,getdate()+1,112)  
  and UpdatedDate is null 
  and Source in ('SASurvey','AAR','CB','RTA','Verve Survey','Unregistered')
  and DataLength(Comments) < 255
  and UpdatedDate is null 
  and PKUsers <> 4678


  open csr
  -- fetch first record
  fetch next from csr into @PKCustomerRecord, @Agent, @CallBackDateTime, @Title, @Forename, @Surname, 
        @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @Address4, @Address5, @PostCode, @ContactNumber, @Telephone2, @DOB, @Source, @list_id, @user_group, @campaign_id,
        @ViciDialID, @Comments

  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin 



        if left(@ContactNumber, 1) = '0' set @ContactNumber = substring(@ContactNumber,2,11)
        if left(@Telephone2, 1) = '0' set @Telephone2 = substring(@Telephone2,2,11)

        insert into VICI...vicidial_list
        (status, entry_date, status, [user],  list_id, gmt_offset_now, called_since_last_reset, phone_code, phone_number, alt_phone, title, 
        first_name, last_name, address1, address2, address3, city, postal_code, date_of_birth, entry_list_id, source_id)
        values
        ('NEW', getdate(), 'CBHOLD', '', @list_id, 1, 'N', '44', @ContactNumber, @Telephone2, @Title, 
        @Forename, @Surname, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @address4, @PostCode, @DOB, @list_id, @Source)

        -- get the ID of the record just inserted
        select @LeadId = max(lead_id) from VICI...vicidial_list

        -- insert the callback record into Vici dial
        insert into VICI...vicidial_callbacks
        (lead_id, list_id, campaign_id, status, entry_time, callback_time, modify_date, [user], recipient, 
        comments, user_group, lead_status)
        values 
        (@LeadId, @list_id, 'CCWarm', 'ACTIVE', getdate(), @CallBackDateTime, getdate(), @ViciUser, 'USERONLY', 
        @Comments, 'CCWarm', 'CALLBK')


        -- fetch next record from CURSOR
        fetch next from csr into @PKCustomerRecord, @Agent, @CallBackDateTime, @Title, @Forename, @Surname, 
        @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @Address4, @Address5, @PostCode, @ContactNumber, @Telephone2, @DOB, @Source, @list_id, @user_group, @campaign_id,
        @ViciDialID, @PKUsers, @Comments

  end -- END OF CURSOR LOOP

  close csr
  deallocate csr
```

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

Comment: Please note that this is completely unnecessary use of cursors. This query can easily be rewritten to use set based operations - specifically to insert all values at once and not one by one. Check this link [Cursors and How to Avoid Them](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them) to see some examples and guidelines. Ask here (or in new question) if you need help doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The number of the columns those you are giving into cursor (after "CURSOR FOR" text) must be matching with the count of parameters you defined to fetch new the record( after "FETCH NEXT FROM csr INTO" text)

23 columns defined to be taken into cursor,  22 of them matched with parameters.